# Update the cache and trigger a re-render in Apollo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to update the cache of a certain item but changes aren't being reflected on to the ui , I have an item which is being fetched by a query that has a lot of variables and I have no access to them on the component that I'm updating that Item on and that Item is also part of a paginated list , so my code was

```js
update = (cache)=>{
 cache.data.data['ItemType_'+itemId].title = "New title"


}
```

as far as I know this code should update the cache of that item but it doesn't show it in the ui , is there a way to update a single item in the cache and have the result rendered ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend running a query with `fetchPolicy: "cache-only"` after you update the cache. That will update the component's data and cause a re-render without hitting the network.

Comment: Adding that to it will result in a re render when updating it ?

Comment: You can use any fetchPolicy that uses cache and pair it with a `cache.modify` call. [See here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#using-cachemodify). 

If you use cache.modify it "triggers a refresh of all active queries that depend on modified fields (unless you override this behavior by passing broadcast: false)"

Answer (score 1):

[You should be able to use `cache.modify`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#using-cachemodify) to publish changes to your cache.

cache.modify "triggers a refresh of all active queries that depend on modified fields (unless you override this behavior by passing broadcast: false)"

You do need to be using a fetchPolicy that [uses cache](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#supported-fetch-policies).

Answer (score 0):

Try and also make sure you are returning the correct data from the mutation.

Return the correct fields from the mutation. The required field can be `id`. If it is not returned from the mutation, then there will be no refresh or re-render.